# How to store and display map location in wagtails

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I am trying to create an API for contact us page. The API take location through map click at wagtail admin panel and send API too. For now I want to know how can I ask user to pin a location and store it in my model. I cant think of anything to do.

`class Contact_UsPage(Page): pass`

My page name is Contact us thank you.

I tried looking at official wagtails documentation and couldn't find anything that would help me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing but Googling "wagtail maps" returned some interesting looking options - including this blog post https://torchbox.com/blog/simple-maps-wagtail-google-and-geopy/ and this CodeRed block https://docs.coderedcorp.com/wagtail-crx/features/blocks/contentblocks/googlemap.html